# Find $P(A\Delta B)$ from $P(A)$, $P(AB)$, and $P(A^cB)$

Tags: probability

a) If $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$ occurrences that satisfy: $P(A)={1\over 6}$, $P(AB)= {1 \over 12}; P(BA^c)={1\over 18}$. Find: $P(A\Delta B)$

b) Prove that for $A,B,C,D \in\mathcal F$ the following applies: $P(ABCD) \leq \sqrt[6]{P(A)P(B)P(C)P(D)}$

For the first i could probably make the answer out, i ask just for reassurence, now the second i have no clue where to start to be honest. Also this last one is accually the product of the probabilities not an intrrsection as some might think..

Comment: What is $\Omega$? What is $F$? What is $P$? Need more information here, it isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: A sample space, Ω, which is the set of all possible outcomes.

Comment: A set of events$ \scriptstyle \mathcal{F}$, where each event is a set containing zero or more outcomes

Comment: The assignment of probabilities to the events; that is, a function P from events to probabilities. Basically the universal definition of a probability space..

Comment: About the post itself: yes please, do explain what you did to solve a). (When you will have, you might turn to b) and note that, at present, b) is just absurd. Are we missing some hypothesis?)

Comment: @OP I just replaced every `\scriptstyle \mathcal` by `\mathcal` since `\scriptstyle` was unnecessary and had unfortunate formatting effects. Re the inequality in b): is your edit intended to say that $P(ABCD)$ in the LHS should actually read $P(A)P(B)P(C)P(D)$? Because then the inequality becomes obvious...

Comment: @Did: Regarding (b), I cannot come up with any quick counterexample; why do you say that it is absurd?

Comment: @AlexM. "Absurd" is incorrect and I wish to withdraw it. What I wanted to point out is that the proof I can come up with proves a *strictly stronger* inequality. Namely, assuming without loss of generality that $P(A)$ is the minimum of $\{P(A),P(B),P(C),P(D)\}$ and noticing that $ABCD\subseteq A$, one gets $$P(ABCD)\le P(A)\le(P(A)P(B)P(C)P(D))^{1/4}.$$ And because $x=P(A)P(B)P(C)P(D)$ is in $(0,1)$ and $x^{2/3}\ge x$ for every such $x$, the RHS happens to be $\le x^{2/3}= (P(A)P(B)P(C)P(D))^{1/6}$.

Comment: @Did: Very nice proof. As a comment, it lacks visibility, so why not post it as an answer?

Comment: *The powers of $x$ in my last comment are incorrect. I guess anybody can correct this but anyway, for most clarity, please replace $x^{2/3}\ge x$ by $x^{1/6}\ge x^{1/4}$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a): $P(A \Delta B) = P((A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus B)) = P(A \setminus B) + P(B \setminus A) = P(A \setminus (A \cap B)) + P(B \cap A^c) = P(A) - P(A \cap B) +  P(B \cap A^c) = \frac 1 6 - \frac 1 {12} + \frac 1 {18} = \frac 5 {36}$.

Comment: How would i prove for example: if A,B,C are independent events in totality then A\B and C are also independent . Essentially prove: P((A\B)C)=P(A\B)P(C)

Comment: $P((A \setminus B) \cap C) = P(A \cap C \setminus B \cap C) = P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) = P(A)P(C) - P(B)P(C) = (P(A)-P(B))P(C) = P(A \setminus B)P(C)$. Anyway, I have an ugly feeling that you are asking us to do your homework, which is not well received in this community.

Comment: Thanks, solved it in the meantime myself :)